# How do I plot the information in a data table based on whether it meets certain criteria?

Tags: r

I have a table which looks like this:

```
                      variant_id            transcript_id HH>0 HH0 HN>0 HN0 NN>0 NN0               tissue
       1: chr1_147517612_T_C_b38 chr1_147648412_147650142  552   0   29   0    0   0 Adipose_Subcutaneous
       2: chr1_147517612_T_C_b38 chr1_147652550_147654193  552   0   29   0    0   0 Adipose_Subcutaneous
       3: chr1_147517612_T_C_b38 chr1_147654327_147655160  552   0   29   0    0   0 Adipose_Subcutaneous
       4: chr1_147517612_T_C_b38 chr1_147659040_147659395  552   0   29   0    0   0 Adipose_Subcutaneous
       5: chr1_147517889_G_A_b38 chr1_147648412_147650142  552   0   29   0    0   0 Adipose_Subcutaneous
      ---                                                                                                
12981138:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38   chr9_34648457_34648761  596   0   71   0    3   0          Whole_Blood
12981139:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38   chr9_34648895_34648997  595   1   71   0    3   0          Whole_Blood
12981140:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38   chr9_34648908_34648997  237 359   25  46    0   3          Whole_Blood
12981141:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38   chr9_34649082_34649409  596   0   71   0    3   0          Whole_Blood
12981142:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38   chr9_34649565_34650368  596   0   71   0    3   0          Whole_Blood
```

I would like to plot the number of unique `transcript_id` values for each ascending value of `HH0` e.g. number of unique `transcript_id`s for `HH0 == 0`, `HH0 == 1`, `HH0 == 2` etc.

How would I got about doing that? Would I use `ggplot`? Not sure where I would even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several other ways to get the counts without `data.table`, such as `sort(table(x$transcript_id))`, though it seems like you are looking for a `data.table`-specific method.

Simple count:

```r
library(data.table)
mtDT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mtDT[, .(n = .N), by = .(cyl, gear)]
#    cyl gear  n
# 1:   6    4  4
# 2:   4    4  8
# 3:   6    3  2
# 4:   8    3 12
# 5:   4    3  1
# 6:   4    5  2
# 7:   8    5  2
# 8:   6    5  1
```

Ascending:

```
mtDT[, .(n = .N), by = .(cyl, gear)][ order(n), ]
#    cyl gear  n
# 1:   4    3  1
# 2:   6    5  1
# 3:   6    3  2
# 4:   4    5  2
# 5:   8    5  2
# 6:   6    4  4
# 7:   4    4  8
# 8:   8    3 12
mtDT[, .(n = .N), by = .(cyl, gear)][ order(gear), ]
#    cyl gear  n
# 1:   6    3  2
# 2:   8    3 12
# 3:   4    3  1
# 4:   6    4  4
# 5:   4    4  8
# 6:   4    5  2
# 7:   8    5  2
# 8:   6    5  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I may not have explained myself well enough. I would like to plot the number of rows with a unique `transcript_id` where `HH0 == 0`, the number of rows with a unique `transcript_id` where `HH0 == 1`... etc. And I would like to do this in a scatterplot. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Just add the other group(s) to your `by=` clause, as in my edit.